# State update not re-rendering in NextJS app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I know, I know, this question gets asked a hundred times a day, but none of the solutions have been working for me. I'm updating a variable using useState and it is not re-rendering any of my components.

I'm POSTing some data using the NextJS API Routing which updates a document in a MongoDB and returns the updated document. Once it's returned, it updates a state with the updated list. I've got a button that just console logs the list variable and it's being updated correctly, but it's not re-rendering anything when it gets updated.

```
// /components/AddNew.jsx

export default function AddNew({ user, list, setList }) {
// ...
        fetch('/api/lists', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.status === 200) {
          console.log(response.list);
          setList([...response.list]);
                    setMessage(<div><strong>{name}</strong> has been added</div>);
                } else {
                    setMessage(<div>Something went wrong, sorry</div>);
                }
            })
// ...
}
```

```
// /api/lists.js

import clientPromise from "../../lib/mongodb";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
    const client = await clientPromise;
    const db = client.db("MY_DATABASE");
    switch (req.method) {
        case "POST":
            let userListExists = await db.collection("lists").findOne({user_id: req.body.user_id});

            if (userListExists) {
                const updateResponse = await db.collection("lists").findOneAndUpdate(
                    { user_id: req.body.user_id },
                    { $push: { list: req.body.list[0] } },
                    { returnOriginal: false }
                );
                const updatedList = updateResponse.value.list;
                res.json({status: 200, list: updatedList});
            } else {
                let newList = await db.collection("lists").insertOne(req.body);
                res.json({status: 200, list: newList});
            }

            break;
        case "GET":
            const userID = req.query.user_id;
            const userList = await db.collection("lists").findOne({user_id: userID});
            res.json({ status: 200, data: userList });
            break;
    }
}
```

The document is being updated correctly, the `response.list` that gets console logged in `AddNew.jsx` is showing the full, updated list, but it's just not re-rendering. I'm certain I'm just missing something glaringly obvious but I just can't see what I'm doing wrong.

`const [list, setList] = useState(false);` are set in a parent component and passed down;

Edit: In the `AddNew` component I'm returning this:

```
    return (
        <div className="add-new">
      <h2>Add new item</h2>
            {message}
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <label>
                    <span>Name of activity</span>
                    <input className="name" type="text" name="name" value={name} onChange={(e) => {
                        setName(e.target.value);
                    }} />
                </label>
                <label>
                    <span>Categories (comma separated)</span>
                    <input className="categories" type="text" name="categories" value={rawCategories} onChange={(e) => {
                        setRawCategories(e.target.value.split(','));
                    }} />
                </label>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
```

and a parent that's being passed the `list` and `setList` from it's component looks like this:

```
import Result from "@/components/Result";
import RandomiseButton from "@/components/RandomiseButton";
import CategorySelector from "@/components/CategorySelector";

import { useState } from "react";
import AddNew from "./AddNew";

export default function Home({ user, list, setList }) {
    const { _id, username } = user;
    const [category, setCategory] = useState('all');
    const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(false);

    let categories = [
        'all',
    ];

  if (list) {
    console.log('has list');
    list.forEach(element => {
      element.categories.forEach(cat => {
        if (!categories.includes(cat)) {
          categories.push(cat);
        }
      });
      console.log(element);
    });
  } else {
    console.log('no list');
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="controls">
        <CategorySelector
          category={category}
          categories={categories}
          setCategory={setCategory}
          list={list}
        />
        <RandomiseButton
          category={category}
          setSelectedItem={setSelectedItem}
          list={list}
        />
      </div>

      <Result selectedItem={selectedItem} list={list} />

      <AddNew user={user} list={list} setList={setList} />
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: What are you returning in your component?

Comment: @devpolo Edited the original post to show what I'm returning now

Comment: Can you try to return a simple list into your Home?

Comment: Like: `return list.map((data) => <div>{data.anyKeyInData}</div>)`

Comment: And remove the DOM manipulation in the`if` statement. Which is a not how you are supposed to manipulate DOM in react.

Comment: Hmmm... it looks like it actually isn't updating the list at all - `list` is just remaining `false`

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by the DOM manipulation in the if statement please? I'm not sure where you mean

Comment: I’m not sure what you are doing with your `categories` but it looks like it you are mutating it to be used in a children. You should use `useState ` instead

Comment: What happened if you log your list right after your `useState `s in the Home?

Answer (score 0):

Embarrassingly, the answer was as simple as a typo - apologies to anyone with this same issue finding this now...

Comment: you should really advise what the typo was and how the change made it work? Otherwise there is little value to the rest of us.